# Refactor pipes interface

Tags: haskell, refactoring, pipe

I'm putting together a model of an encoder using the pipes library (4.1.4).

I have a working function

```
encode :: (Monad m) => Int -> -                 -- number of codes per bit
                       Producer Word32 m r ->   -- code source
                       Producer Word32 m r ->   -- data source
                       Producer Word32 m r      -- resulting stream
encode n cp dp = P.zipWith xor cp (dp >-> (upsample n))
```

And I'd like to refactor it as

```
encode :: (Monad m) => Int -> 
                       Producer Word32 m r ->
                       Pipe Word32 m r
```

I think its usage is clearer; it encodes data flowing through the pipe. I haven't the first idea how to achieve this.

EDIT

```
upsample :: Int -> Pipe Word32 Word32 m r
```

Comment: Are you wanting to somehow combine the two `Producer` arguments?

Comment: I'd like to partially apply a code producer and be left with a pipe

Comment: Does ```encode n cp = (do { c <- cp; x <- await; yield $ c `xor` x}) >-> upsample n``` work?

Comment: Your types aren't quite right though, should return a `Pipe Word32 Word32 m ()`.

Comment: It might be possible to write a general function `(Monad m) => (Producer a m r -> Producer b m r) -> Proxy () a () b m r`. I'm not sure if it'd require a bias towards blocking on request or return or if it'd require more from the underlying `Monad`.

Comment: Any thoughts on that generalisation? I'd have thought that if it could be formed, the opposite, from pipe to a function taking and emitting producer could be done

Comment: @OlliB I posed the generalization as another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367170/construct-a-pipes-proxy-inside-out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
encode n cp = upsample n >-> f cp where
  f c = do
           r <- lift $ next c
           case r of
             Left r -> return r -- use f cp here, if you really meant Viginere
             Right (x, c') -> do
                             y <- await
                             yield $ x `xor` y
                             f c'
```

Here `encode` will await for the value from `cp`: if it becomes available, it will remember the value and get one value from `upsample` pipe, `yield` the encoded value, and loop to `encode` the remainder of the `Producer` left from `cp` after removing `x`. That way it will iterate the `cp` and data in parallel, just like `zipWith`.

---

I don't know what `upsample` is like, so I defined is as a negating pipe:

```
upsample :: Monad m => Int -> Pipe Int Int m r
upsample n = do
               x<-await
               yield $ -x
               upsample n

encode n cp = (upsample n) >-> f cp where
  f cp = do
           r <- lift $ next cp
           case r of
             Left r -> return r
             Right (x,cp) -> do
                               y <- await
                               yield $ x*y -- I was lazy to import Bits
                               f cp

Prelude Pipes> runEffect $ mapM_ yield [0..] >->
                           encode 10 (mapM_ yield [1..10]) >->
                           sequence_ (repeat $ do {x <- await; lift $ print x})
0
-2  -- remember, [0..] is negated by upsample, then multiplied by [1..10]
-6
-12
-20
-30
-42
-56
-72
-90  -- only 10 items were available in `cp`, so only 10 items printed
```