# Construct a pipes Proxy inside-out

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

Is it possible to make a function so that a `Proxy` from [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes) can be constructed inside-out? By inside-out, I mean create a proxy from a function that connects the upstream and downstream connections. The most desirable (but impossible) signature would be

```
makeProxy :: (Monad m) =>
             (Server a' a m r -> Client b' b m r -> Effect m r) ->
              Proxy  a' a               b' b               m r
```

The first problem we encounter is the mechanical problem of constructing the `Proxy`. There's no way for us to know if the function looks at the `Server` or `Client` except by having each of them be `M`, in which case we'll only know which one it looked at, not what value it tried to send upstream or downstream. If we focus on the upstream end, the only thing we know is that something tried to figure out what the upstream proxy is, so we need to decide on either always resulting in a `Request` farther upstream or `Respond`ing. Either way we answer, the only value we can provide is `()`. This means we can make a `Request ()` to an upstream producer or `Respond ()` immediately. If we consider making this choice for both ends, there are only four possible functions. The following functions are named after whether their upstream and downstream connections send interesting data downstream (`D`) or upstream (`U`).

```
betweenDD :: (Monad m) =>
             (Server () a m r -> Client () b m r -> Effect m r) ->
              Proxy  () a               () b               m r
betweenDD = undefined

betweenDU :: (Monad m) =>
             (Server () a m r -> Client b' () m r -> Effect m r) ->
              Proxy  () a               b' ()               m r
betweenDU = undefined

betweenUU :: (Monad m) =>
             (Server a' () m r -> Client b' () m r -> Effect m r) ->
              Proxy  a' ()               b' ()               m r
betweenUU f = reflect (betweenDD g)
    where g source sink = f (reflect sink) (reflect source)


betweenUD :: (Monad m) =>
             (Server a' () m r -> Client () b m r -> Effect m r) ->
              Proxy  a' ()               () b               m r
betweenUD = undefined
```

`betweenDD` is the most interesting, it would build a pipe between a `Producer` and a `Consumer`; `betweenUU` would do the same for a pipe running upstream. `betweenDU` would consume data requesting it from one of two sources. `betweenUD` would produce data, sending it to one of two destinations.

Can we provide a definition for `betweenDD`? If not, can we instead provide definitions for the following simpler functions?

```
belowD :: (Monad m) =>
          (Producer a m r -> Producer b m r) ->
           Proxy () a              () b m r

aboveD :: (Monad m) =>
          (Consumer b m r -> Consumer a m r) ->
           Proxy () a              () b m r
```

This question was motivated by trying to write `belowD` to use in answering a [question about `P.zipWith`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27361127/414413).

#### Example

This example happens to be essentially [the question that inspired this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27361127/414413).

Let's say we want to create a `Pipe` that will `number` the values passing through it. The `Pipe` will have values `a` coming downstream from above and values `(n, a)` leaving downstream below; in other words it will be a `Pipe a (n, a)`.

We'll solve this problem by `zip`ping with the numbers. The result of `zip`ing with the numbers is a function `(->)` from a `Producer a` to a `Producer (n, a)`.

```
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

number' :: (Monad m, Num n, Enum n) => Producer a m () -> Producer (n, a) m ()
number' = P.zip (fromList [1..])
```

Even though the `Pipe` will consume `a`s from upstream, from the point of view of the function it needs a `Producer` of `a`s to provide those values. If we had a definition for `belowD` we could write

```
number :: (Monad m, Num n, Enum n) => Pipe a (n, a) m ()
number = belowD (P.zip (fromList [1..]))
```

given a suitable definition for `fromList`

```
fromList :: (Monad m) => [a] -> Producer a m ()
fromList []     = return ()
fromList (x:xs) = do
    yield x
    fromList xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think `makeProxy` is possible if you slightly change the type.  I am on my phone so I cannot type check this just yet, but I believe this works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Pipes.Core

makeProxy
    ::  Monad m
    =>  (   forall n. Monad n
        =>  (a' -> Server a' a n r)
        ->  (b  -> Client b' b n r)
        ->         Effect      n r
        )
    ->  Proxy a' a b' b m r
makeProxy k = runEffect (k up dn)
  where
    up = lift . request \>\ pull
    dn = push />/ lift . respond
```

This assumes that `k` is defined as:

```
k up dn = up ->> k >>~ dn
```

Edit: Yeah, it works if you add an import for `lift`

I'll walk through why this works.

First, let me set out some of the `pipes` definitions and laws:

```
-- Definition of `push` and `pull`
(1) pull = request >=> push
(2) push = respond >=> pull

-- Read this as: f * (g + h) = (f * g) + (f * h)
(3) f \>\ (g >=> h) = (f \>\ g) >=> (f \>\ h)

-- Read this as: (g + h) * f = (g * f) + (h * f)
(4) (g >=> h) />/ f = (g />/ f) >=> (h />/ f)

-- Right identity law for the request category
(5) f \>\ request = f

-- Left identity law for the respond category
(6) respond />/ f = f

-- Free theorems (equations you can prove from the types alone!)
(7) f \>\ respond = respond
(8) request />/ f = request
```

Now let's use those equations to expand out `up` and `dn`:

```
up = (lift . request) \>\ pull
   = (lift . request) \>\ (request >=> push)  -- Equation (1)
   = (lift . request \>\ request) >=> (lift . request \>\ push)  -- Equation (3)
   = lift . request >=> (lift . request \>\ push)                -- Equation (5)
   = lift . request >=> (lift . request \>\ (respond >=> pull))  -- Equation (2)
   = lift . request >=> (lift . request \>\ respond) >=> (lift . request \>\ pull) -- Equation (3)
   = lift . request >=> respond >=> (lift . request \>\ pull)    -- Equation (7)
up = lift . request >=> respond >=> up

-- Same steps, except symmetric
dn = lift . respond >=> request >=> dn
```

In other words, `up` converts all `request`s going out of `k`'s upstream interface into `lift . request` and `dn` converts all `respond`s going out of `k`'s downstream interface into `lift . respond`.  In fact, we can prove that:

```
(9)  (f \>\ pull) ->> p = f \>\ p
(10) p >>~ (push />/ f) = p />/ f
```

... and if we apply those equations to `k`, we get:

```
  (lift . request \>\ pull) ->> k >>~ (push />/ lift . respond)
= lift . request \>\ k />/ lift . respond
```

This says the same thing except more directly: we're replacing every `request` in `k` with `lift . request` and replacing every `respond` in `k` with `lift . respond`.

Once we lower all `request`s and `respond`s to the base monad, we end up with this type:

```
lift . request \>\ k />/ lift . respond :: Effect' (Proxy a' a b' b m) r
```

Now we can delete the outer `Effect` using `runEffect`.  This leaves behind the "inside-out" `Proxy`.

This is also the same trick that `Pipes.Lift.distribute` uses to swap the order of the `Proxy` monad with the monad underneath it:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/src/Pipes-Lift.html#distribute

Comment: That covers the case I called `betweenDU` where all of the interesting data is flowing in. `betweenDU f = makeProxy g where g fa' fb = f (fa' ()) (fb ())`

Comment: @Cirdec You can't satisfy your original signature for `makeProxy`, because both the `Server` and `Client` are missing an argument.  In a composed `Proxy` pipeline, every `Proxy` except (at most) one must take an argument (the types enforce this).  Both your `Server` and `Client` are argument-free, which means they are impossible to connect in general.

Answer (score 2):

(Sorry, I missed a couple brackets on a sleepy head, so the first answer was to a different question)

`Producer' a m r -> Producer' b m r` is the definition of a `Pipe a b m r` - it can consume `a` and produce `b`.

```
belowD ::Monad m => (Producer' a m () -> Producer' b m r) -> Pipe a b m ()
belowD g = sequence_ $ repeat $ do
             x <- await -- wait for `a` as a Pipe
             g $ yield x -- pass a trivial Producer to g, and forward output
```

This one will expect one or more `b` for each `a`. If `g` needs more than one `a` to produce one `b`, it won't produce anything.

---

But then since `Proxy a b c d m` is a `Monad`, we can lift `await`:

```
belowD :: Monad m => (forall m . Monad m => Producer a m () -> Producer b m r) ->
                     Pipe a b m r
belowD g = h . g $ sequence_ $ repeat ((lift $ await) >>= yield) where
  h :: Monad m => Producer b (Pipe a b m) r -> Pipe a b m r
  h p = do
      x <- next p
      case x of
        Left r -> return r
        Right (x,p) -> do
                         yield x
                         h p

h :: Monad m => Producer a m () -> Producer a m ()
h :: Monad m => Producer a m () -> Producer a m ()
h p = p >-> (sequence_ $ repeat $ await >>= yield >> await) -- skips even

main = runEffect $ (mapM_ yield [1..10]) >-> (for (belowD h) $ lift . print)

> 1
> 3
> 5
> 7
> 9
```